# What could cause TCP to retransmit only the end of a (fully acknowledged) segment?

Tags: tcp

The gist of this question is in the title: what could cause TCP to retransmit only the end of a (fully acknowledged) segment?

Here is a TCP conversation between two hosts: a SSH server (172.16.6.249, physical machine) and a SSH client, executing the command "ssh-keyscan" (192.168.0.18, virtual machine). This capture was done on the network interface of 192.168.0.18.

```
No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
  1 0.000000    192.168.0.18          172.16.6.249          TCP      74     46180 > 22 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=28200 Len=0 MSS=1410 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=173592928 TSecr=0 WS=128
  2 0.001274    172.16.6.249          192.168.0.18          TCP      74     22 > 46180 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=28960 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=3139755418 TSecr=173592928 WS=128
  3 0.001309    192.168.0.18          172.16.6.249          TCP      66     46180 > 22 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=28288 Len=0 TSval=173592929 TSecr=3139755418
  4 0.010710    172.16.6.249          192.168.0.18          TCP      109    22 > 46180 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=29056 Len=43 TSval=3139755421 TSecr=173592929
  5 0.010741    192.168.0.18          172.16.6.249          TCP      66     46180 > 22 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=44 Win=28288 Len=0 TSval=173592931 TSecr=3139755421
  6 0.010886    192.168.0.18          172.16.6.249          TCP      91     46180 > 22 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=44 Win=28288 Len=25 TSval=173592931 TSecr=3139755421
  7 0.010965    192.168.0.18          172.16.6.249          TCP      1464   46180 > 22 [ACK] Seq=26 Ack=44 Win=28288 Len=1398 TSval=173592931 TSecr=3139755421
  8 0.011950    172.16.6.249          192.168.0.18          TCP      66     22 > 46180 [ACK] Seq=44 Ack=26 Win=29056 Len=0 TSval=3139755421 TSecr=173592931
  9 0.011959    192.168.0.18          172.16.6.249          TCP      284    46180 > 22 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1424 Ack=44 Win=28288 Len=218 TSval=173592931 TSecr=3139755421
 10 0.012227    172.16.6.249          192.168.0.18          TCP      66     22 > 46180 [ACK] Seq=44 Ack=1424 Win=31872 Len=0 TSval=3139755421 TSecr=173592931
 11 0.033124    172.16.6.249          192.168.0.18          TCP      1714   22 > 46180 [PSH, ACK] Seq=44 Ack=1424 Win=31872 Len=1648 TSval=3139755421 TSecr=173592931
 12 0.033153    192.168.0.18          172.16.6.249          TCP      66     46180 > 22 [ACK] Seq=1642 Ack=1692 Win=31616 Len=0 TSval=173592937 TSecr=3139755421
 13 0.033173    172.16.6.249          192.168.0.18          TCP      316    [TCP Retransmission] 22 > 46180 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1442 Ack=1642 Win=34688 Len=250 TSval=3139755424 TSecr=173592931
 14 0.033184    192.168.0.18          172.16.6.249          TCP      78     [TCP Dup ACK 12#1] 46180 > 22 [ACK] Seq=1642 Ack=1692 Win=31616 Len=0 TSval=173592937 TSecr=3139755424 SLE=1442 SRE=1692
 15 0.035635    192.168.0.18          172.16.6.249          TCP      114    46180 > 22 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1642 Ack=1692 Win=31616 Len=48 TSval=173592937 TSecr=3139755424
 16 0.047742    172.16.6.249          192.168.0.18          TCP      690    22 > 46180 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1692 Ack=1690 Win=34688 Len=624 TSval=3139755430 TSecr=173592937
 17 0.047869    192.168.0.18          172.16.6.249          TCP      66     46180 > 22 [FIN, ACK] Seq=1690 Ack=2316 Win=34304 Len=0 TSval=173592940 TSecr=3139755430
 18 0.049738    172.16.6.249          192.168.0.18          TCP      66     22 > 46180 [FIN, ACK] Seq=2316 Ack=1691 Win=34688 Len=0 TSval=3139755430 TSecr=173592940
```

I don't understand the frames 13 and 14. 172.16.6.249 already sent a segment with sequence number 44 + length 1648 = 1692 (frame 11), to which 192.168.0.18 answered *only* with an ACK 1692 (frame 12).

What could make 172.16.6.249 send again the end of the segment (frame 13)? I have checked the segment payload and it does match the last 250 bytes of the payload in frame 11.

I also assume the selective acknowledgement of these last 250 bytes in frame 14 is the result of the client being confused by receiving the same data twice, but maybe I am missing something here.

I unfortunately don't have the corresponding capture on 172.16.6.249, as I am investigating network issues that are hard to reproduce.

The hosts are physically very close, with only one (Linux) router between them and one physical switch, but there is some SDN going on (Linux bridges + VXLAN). This however should be transparent to the endpoints.

What should I be looking at next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your capture is scooped due to some form of TCP segmenation offload on your host.  I doubt that the packets appeared on the wire as shown.  Notice that frame 11 has a reported length of 1714 octets, too long for most Ethernet LANs.

Comment: Yes, this is above the MTU of network interface (and of the actual network). Seems like the payload was segmented by the client, and only the last segment was correctly received by the server. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: And I do have TCP segmentation offload enabled on this host.

Comment: That frame 14 is horrible too.  The SLE/SRE described is within the ack number.  SLE/SRE should all be greater than ack since they should describe blocks of data within the window.  I think you'll need to capture off the wire or on a router monitor port to really know whether there are any problems in this flow.  Capturing on the other host may help but that might be subject to the same nonsense.

Answer (score -1):

The most likely scenario is that Frame 11 was not received by 192.168.0.18 correctly, either due to fragmentation (as eluded to by @Benoit Faucon), or general packet loss.

If the problem is consistent (e.g.: it always happens when you execute ssh-keyscan) I would see if you can get a similar capture from the remote host and compare it's point-of-view.

Comment: Fragmentation is at the IP level, TCP either gets the full IP datagram or it does not.

Comment: The problem is unfortunately not consistent, and hard to reproduce. I see some brief windows of packet loss (and duplicate acks) on this network.

Comment: @marctxk right, but we're only seeing what was sent, not what was received

Comment: If frame 11 had not been received then there would not be `Ack=1692` in frame 12.

Comment: @hertitu right you are - completely missed that